# How can I receive and verify WS-Federation tokens in python/django?

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, saml, ws-federation

I am trying to implement an assertion consumer for signed WS-Federation tokens as part of a SSO system. I know that simplesamlphp has (undocumented) ws-fed support, but I'm using a Django stack.  It looks like djangosaml2 pysaml2 doesn't support the WS-Federation specification as they expect XML with a 'Response' root node, and not a 'RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection' root node.

Has anyone run into this before? Is there a python library out there that can help me? I'm tempted just to roll my own *consumer*, but I'm afraid I might slip up and create a security vulnerability due to my lack of **X509** and **xml** knowledge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use [django-auth-adfs](https://github.com/jobec/django-auth-adfs) for adfs authentication. I'm not sure how WS-Federation fits in the mix in a Python application, however, *if* you are authenticating to ADFS, this library does a decent job.

Comment: lol, just noted the date of the question - assume you have your problem solved by now.